# What happened if I don't deactivate environment anaconda?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I wonder if there is any problem if I just close the terminal without `deactivate`. Or when I change the environment, do I need to deactivate the environment I'm working in or I just need to `activate other-env`.

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem when you try to close the terminal without `deactivate`, the `activate` is only affected within terminal session.

And if you want to change env, just `activate` it without `deactivate` the old one

Answer (score 2):

Closing the window without deactivating should be fine. You can also just activate the new environment without deactivating first.

The same goes for virtualenv.

Comment: So the `deactivate` seems useless?

Comment: @Ha Born Sometimes you do not want any environment active though.